# While loop webview.geturl().contains crashes webview

Tags: android, webview, while-loop, contains

When my function completes I want my webview to go back to the dashboard page however my current loop crashes the webview. Any better suggestions, or am I just going about it completely wrong?

Current code:

```
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mWrappedInstance.onFinish();
            while (!mWebView.getUrl().contains("dashboard")) {
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have so many statements.... Please tell which statement does it.

Comment: You will have an exception. Which one. Post the logcat.

Comment: Ever checked if .getUrl()returns null?

Comment: @greenapps No I havn't checked if geturl returns null. Will check now.

Comment: You did not answer my question at all.

Comment: @greenapps this is true. Thank you for trying to assist, but I was able to fix it by adding an else statement with a break. Closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected error by using the following:

```
while (!mWebView.getUrl().contains("dashboard")) {
            if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            }else{
                mWebView.goBack();
                break;
            }
```